# Regex Capture group causing issue with optional pattern in regex with negative look-ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Using capture groups to get specific pieces of a string. It has worked before, but now that I have optional character groups using ? optional param I am getting weird results.

I am attempting to capture Critical care medicine as a capture group within a string, allow CRIT abbreviation and Medicine optional. Exclude capture group if followed by an "and".

https://regex101.com/r/MeWB7J/1

REGEX: `.*((?:(?:\bCRIT(?:ICAL)?\W*CARE\W*(?:MEDICINE)?))(?!\sAND)).*`

If I pass it CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE, CRITICAL CARE, or CRIT CARE works fine and I get back expected results in my capture group. However if I pass "CRITICAL CARE MEDICINE AND", my capture group will be "CRITICAL CARE". If I pass "CRIT CARE AND", I get "CRIT CARE". I'm lost on why the negative lookahead isn't working and is being treated as essentially an ignore that part of the pattern.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally capture MEDICINE in the capture group, if after matching care there is no MEDICINE followed by AND

Note that `\W` and `\s` can also match a newline.

```
.*\b(CRIT(?:ICAL)?\W*CARE\b(?!(?:\s+MEDICINE\b)?\s+AND\b)(?:\s+MEDICINE\b)?).*
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*` Match the whole line
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `CRIT(?:ICAL)?` Match CRIT or CRITICAL
  - `\W*CARE\b` Match optional non word chars and then match the word CARE
  - `(?!` Negative lookhead, assert what is directly to the righ tis not

    - `(?:\s+MEDICINE\b)?` Optionally match  `MEDICINE`
    - `\s+AND\b` Match  `AND`
  - )` Close the lookahead
  - `(?:\s+MEDICINE\b)?` Optionally match  `MEDICINE`
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1I7Jh/1).